# Timeout on asynchronous socket operation with SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, timeout

There seems to be no way to specify a timeout on the `AcceptAsync()` method of the .NET `Socket` class. It accepts a `SocketAsyncEventArgs`

```
if (!socket.AcceptAsync(awaitable.EventArgs))
   doasync();
else
   dosync();
```

Any suggestions on how to make this method timeout after a particular time frame? It seems to apply to the `ReceiveAsync()` method as well.

The `Socket` itself has some timeout values, like `ReceiveTimeout`, but the documentation indicates they do not apply to asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReceiveTimeout` isn't as useful as many people think. Besides that it's only applicable to synchronous `Receive()` method calls, there is also that the socket is unusable after a timeout occurs. There is no way to have a receive operation timeout on a socket and then resume reading from the same socket.

So the alternative that always works regardless of type of operation, turns out to be fine. Specifically:

- Set a timer for the timeout period you want
- Attempt the operation
- If the operation completes before the timeout, disable the timer (or if completing an operation is to be immediately followed by another attempt at the operation, restart the timer)
- If the operation does *not* complete before the timeout, **close the socket**.

Closing the socket will cause any pending I/O operation to complete with an exception. Of course, having closed the socket, you won't be able to use that socket again. But that's how the underlying socket API works anyway, so that's not a problem.

Note that your timer and the socket operation are racing. So it's important not only to implement the timer, but to synchronize the operation and the timer. E.g. use a `volatile bool` flag to signal that the operation completed successfully and that even if the timer handler is invoked, it should not close the socket.

Comment: I had hoped to be able to supply a timeout to the asynchronous operation so that I could have the socket close without having to provide an additional 'monitoring' thread, I guess that's the best way though.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple way to do this, no need to set a timer

```
Task[] acceptTask = new Task[] { Task.Delay(1000), socket.AcceptAsync() };

await Task.WhenAny(acceptTask);

if (acceptTask[1].Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation) //check the task status
    Console.WriteLine("timeout");
else
    Console.WriteLine("connected");
```

for AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e):

```
private static async void TimeoutCheck(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine(e.AcceptSocket.RemoteEndPoint); //you can do a timeout check here
}
socket.AcceptAsync(e);
TimeoutCheck(e);
```

I have to say this is **not** a good idea for people who needs accurate timeout, since a task is only promised to complete sometime in the future, but it works in some simple scenarios.